# Optimal Poincare constant in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I want to check the validity of my approach to finding a tigehter bound on the Poincare constant in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded open set. This will be somewhat long, so I will divide this post into sections.

**Problem Statement**: Let $u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, with $2<p<\infty$. There is a constant $C$, depending only on $\Omega$ and $p$ such that $\forall u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ , we have $||u||_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq C||\nabla u||_{L^p(\Omega)}$

**Results**: Optimal $L^1(\Omega)$ and $L^2(\Omega)$ estimates have been found already for convex domains.

If $u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, then $u\in L^p(\Omega)$. I will add the assumption $u\in W_0^{1,q}(\Omega)$, Now consider the Poincare inequality.

$||u||_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq C||\nabla u||_{L^p(\Omega)}$

Note that the Lebesgue measure $\mu(\Omega)$ is finite, as $\Omega$ is a bounded set. This allows us to use $L^p$ "nesting theorem".

The statement of this theorem is:

Let $1\leq p<q\leq \infty$, $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$, then $||u||_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq \mu(\Omega)^{(1/p)-(1/q)}||u||_{L^q(\Omega)}$, which shows $L^q(\Omega)\subset L^p(\Omega)$. The proof of this statement can be found here:

[How to show that $L^p$ spaces are nested?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21460/how-to-show-that-lp-spaces-are-nested)

This essentially tells us if we have $u\in L^q(\Omega)$, we also have $u\in L^p(\Omega)$. That said, depending on the constant $L=\mu(\Omega)^{(1/p)-(1/q)}$, $||u||_{L^p}$ is not smaller than the $L^q$ norm if $0<L<1$. We can partition the result into two cases, starting with $L\geq 1$.

My plan here is to play around with the $L^p$ and $L^q$ norms of $u$ and $\nabla u$, and the constant $L$, to get a decent, if not optimal bound on the Poincare constant $C$. I am optimistic about when the geometry of $\Omega$ is nice enough, where $\mu(\Omega)=1$.

**Addendum**: I also would like to reconcile this with the optimal $L^1$ and $L^2$ estimates already known, and I am curious as to what happens if $\Omega$ is disconnected. My hunch is that the value of the norms would change, but my approach wouldn't, as it does not utilize connectedness of the domain $\Omega$

Comment: I would not be optimistic. You will have to dig into the proof of the Poincare inequality to say anything about the constant. You said you are familiar with the convex case, maybe you should review the proof of the optimal constants in that case.

Comment: What do you mean by optimal? The $L^2$-Poincaré constant is just the spectral gap of the Dirichlet Laplacian, I doubt that one can compute it for arbitrary convex domains.

Comment: Close to optimal constants are known for convex domains. Here, there is a direct proof of the Poincare inequality (not the proof by contradiction that is used for arbitrary domains). I haven't looked recently, but I believe the optimality of the constant is just with respect to the dependence on the diameter of the domain.